# How to send http put request in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic3, slim

hi this is my api and that work with postman

```
$app->put('/mmsg/{id}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
  require_once('dbconnect.php');
  $mmsg_id = $args['id'];
  $query = "update mmsg set m_pay=1 where mmsg_id=$mmsg_id";
  $result = $contomysql->query($query);
});
```

how i send the mmsg_id to this with ionic

please help this is my college project and I got stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpClient` module in `angular/common/http`.

`HttpClient` **PUT** request has 3 parameters.

1. url
2. body
3. options

You can send HttpHeaders/HttpParams in options parameter.

Example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class SampleService {

  API: string = "www.example.com/mmsg";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  update(): Observable<any> {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let params = new HttpParams().append('id': 1);
    let options = { headers: headers, params: params };

    return this.http.put(this.API, null, options);
  }
}
```

More information see the [documentation.](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#put)